# Не получается наладить связь между сервисами внутри Docker-контенейра (HTTP)

Tags: java, spring, http, docker

Проблема в следующем: я делаю проект используя Spring Boot и в моем проекте есть два модуля, которые должны функционировать отдельно друг от друга и общаться между собой через HTTP протокол.
Данные модули уже написаны и готовы и теперь я пытаюсь запустить это всё в контейнере Docker и всё запускается — я могу полноценно пользоваться сервисом, но при попытке использовать функцию, которая отправляет HTTP-запрос второму модулю (через RestTemplate), получается, что модули друг друга не видят. Когда я разрабатывал приложение без Docker, то адреса были такими:

1. Основной модуль на порту 8080 `http://localhost:8080`
2. Второй модуль на порту 8081 и обращался я к нему по адресу, передавая некоторые значения в body `http://localhost:8081/compile`

Теперь, когда я запустил эти модули в Docker, связав через Docker Compose, при обращении к такому адресу я получаю ошибку, вот мой docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  app:
    container_name: dexterity
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    command: java -jar --spring.profiles.active=dev dexterity.jar
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/dexterity
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: 1234
    depends_on:
      - db
      - compileta
    networks:
      - compileta

  compileta:
    container_name: compileta
    image: compileta
    ports:
    - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - compileta

  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234
      POSTGRES_DB: dexterity
    restart: always
    networks:
      - compileta

networks:
  compileta:
    driver: bridge
```

Как правильно настроить такую сеть в Docker? Много времени потратил на поиск, но так и не смог разобраться.

Если вдруг нужны ещё какие-то подробности, спрашивайте. Отвечу быстро, очень нужна помощь

P.S. Модуль app является основным, модуль compileta — вторым, то есть тем, с которым связывается app

Comment: столкнулся с такой же проблемой. подскажите пожалуйста вам помог ответ данный ниже?(просто я сделал как сказано ниже, но к сажалению что то не так) может в самом коде я не так как то делаю вызов...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда запускаете локально, то сервис compileta доступен по имени хоста localhost. В docker-compose он будет доступен по имени `compileta` (т.е. совпадает с именем сервиса docker-compose).

То есть вам нужно добавить (если еще нет такого) параметр в основное приложение, который будет указывать по какому адресу соединяться с `compileta`.

И потом нужно его задать в конфигурации сервиса `app` в docker-compose. Лучше всего через переменную окружения, аналогично тому, как задается адрес БД. Если параметр будет называться `compileta.url`, то тогда конфигурация будет такой:

```
  ...
  app:
    container_name: dexterity
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    command: java -jar --spring.profiles.active=dev dexterity.jar
    environment:
      COMPILETA_URL: http://compileta:8081/compile
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/dexterity
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
   ...
```

А в главном сервисе в классе который обращается к compileta должно быть что-то типа:

```
class SomeService {

@Value("${compileta.url}")
String compiletaUrl;
...
}
```

Comment: Спасаете меня сегодня)

Comment: в одном месте называете переменную `COMPILETA_URL`, в двух других — `compileta.url`. имена разные. неужели java поймёт, что речь об одной и той же переменной?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Да, это неочевидная фича spring boot. Для того чтоб нормально работала передача параметров через переменные окружения (где не всегда хорошо работают имена с точками), спринг делает автоматическую конвертацию: `most operating systems disallow period-separated key names, but you can use underscores instead (for example, SPRING_CONFIG_NAME instead of spring.config.name)`